# php registration fails to exit when using die()

Tags: php, registration, exit

My PHP piece of code for registration is not working properly. When I enter an email already in use and/or username already in use, it does register the user again, although I have made IF statements to check if user with this name or email already exists. Here is the piece of code:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
{
    $username = mysql_prep($_POST['firstname']);
    $password = mysql_prep($_POST['password']);
    $email    = mysql_prep($_POST['email']);
    $ip       = mysql_prep($_POST['ip']);
    $sex      = mysql_prep($_POST['sex']);

    $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    if ($conn) 
    {
        $select_db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

        if ($select_db) 
        {
            $sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'"
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) 
            {
                die("Email already registered");
            }

            $sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'"
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) 
            {
                die("Username already exists");
            }

            $sql  = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`)
                     VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}', '{$email}' '{$sex}')"

            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

            if($result)
            {
                echo "true";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "false";
            }

    }
    else
    {
        die("Cannot select database!<br />" . mysql_error());
    }
}
else 
{
    die("Cannot connect to database!<br />" . mysql_error());
}
}
else 
{
  echo "<h1>Sorry, you have no place here :)</h1>";
}
```

mysql_prep() is function that makes the input data real_escape_string for safety.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can tell me how to fix this issues will be good :)

Comment: Thanks, I will have that in mind - I am already using mysql_real_escape_string, but if you can help me to first fix my issues - I will really appreciate it. I want to make it work first, and then to make it secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug the error, why don't you echo the $sql variable in the browser(the one before die()) and then copy it and see the output in phpmyadmin.
If it returns then proceed forward until you find the error.
You could also use php's built in functions but I always find this approach easier.

Comment: Tnx, it helped me for other things.

Answer (score 0):

use query like this with concatenate operator.

```
 $sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
```

Edited

```
$sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'"
$sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'"
$sql  = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}', '{$email}' '{$sex}')"
```

ok replace these lines with and check again this will take maximum 2 min

```
$sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
$sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$sql  = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."' '".$sex."')";
```

Comment: Is there any difference between email = '{$email}'" and email = '".$email."'" ?

Comment: yes if you will echo this you will get output as it is '{$email}' because variable not works in single quote. is this answer working for you?

Comment: I will answer you as soon as my friend and I try it, but the registration actually works, only the check fails - even when the username or email exists, it registers you again. I am pretty sure that not using concatenate operator isn't the real problem - the database updates correctly.

Comment: My version and your version are both working, 
`$sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'"
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) 
            {
                die("Email already registered");
            }

            $sql  = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'"
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) 
            {
                die("Username already exists");
            }` 
This is not working.

Comment: I fixed my problem when I rewrote my code, and it is working without concatenation - it's not a necessity.